# Maximum acceleration of an object pulled at an angle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, friction

A box with mass $0.2 \;\text{kg}$ is being drawn on a horizontal surface with a force $2.0 \;\text{N}$. The force is constantly angled $40°$ relative to the surface, the friction coefficient between the surface and box is $0.23$

Box mass = $0.2 \;\text{kg}$
Force = $2.0 \;\text{N}$
$μ = 0.23$
Angle = $40°$

**Problem A:**: Whats the acceleration of the box?

**Thoughts of my own**: We have four forces acting on the object, friction, Normal force(N), gravity(G) and $F_x$ and $F_y$

I start by finding the acceleration with our given values,

firstly we know that $N=G$ because of newtons second law, we only need to worry about forces in $x$ direction
$$
\sum F_x= F_x-μmg
 $$
$$
F_x=\cos(40°)\cdot2.0-0.23\cdot0.2\cdot9.81=1.08 \;\text{N}
$$
$$
a=\frac{F_{x}}{m} = \frac{1.08}{0.2}=5.4 \;\text{m/s^2}
$$
**Problem B:**: Whats the maximal acceleration of the box before it loses contact with the surface? Only F changes, the angle is unchanged

This is where I need some help, I've thought about finding the maximum acceleration with our friction since there must be a limit to how fast this thing can accelerate with regards to our friction, my other idea is that at some point $$F_y+N>G$$ and then the object will loose contact with the surface.

Comment: There is an error in the problem statement. First it says that F = 2 Nt.  Then it says that only F changes.

Comment: My bad, was a question with two parts and I forgot to include the first one

Comment: The unit of measurement of acceleration is $\mathrm{ms^{-2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

If F changes, you start by finding an F which makes the Normal force zero.

Comment: N=1.962N, F+N=G